# Why can't I edit these closed questions?

Tags: support, editing, tagging

I opened up the [untagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag to clear it out. I came across two question that I could not edit:

- [Help with this strange wording “…on the wrong side of God” [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134308/help-with-this-strange-wording-on-the-wrong-side-of-god)
- [What is “Development of effectiveness measure?” [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143541/what-is-development-of-effectiveness-measure)

Not only that but I cannot vote to reopen or delete.

Both questions say "comments disabled on deleted / locked posts", but neither has the locked banner.

Are these questions actually locked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A question that has been migrated from another site and then closed counts as a rejected migration and will be automatically locked. At the same time, the question is unlocked (but not reopened) on the original site.

MSO has an outstanding (as in not completed) [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130116/show-lock-banners-on-rejected-migrations) to display the lock banner.

Given that the OP in both cases never created an account on EL&U and the closures were not outrageously incorrect, I have deleted both questions.

Comment: The MSO request has been implemented: the migration banner now says "migration rejected", and explains that the post can be edited/reopened on its original site.